# Importing Data from Access into Excel weekly using ADO

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I am trying to automate a data pull from Access into Excel using ADO. Each week I pull in the previous weeks deals from Monday-Friday. Right now I have SQL pulling in the deals from the previous week, however the way I have it right now I would manually have to change the dates in the code each week. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Below is the code I currently have:

```
Sub Import()
  'Declaring the necessary variables
  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim dbPath As String
  Dim SQL As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim var As Range

  cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
  "Data Source=xxx"

  'create the SQL statement to retrieve the data from the table
  sSQL = "SELECT * FROM BP_Closed_Deals WHERE Start_Date between '10/21/2019' and '10/25/2019'"

  'create the ADODB recordset object
  Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

  'connectionString open
  rs.Open sSQL, cn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

  If Not rsData.EOF Then
      Sheets("Deals_2018_Copy").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsData
      rsData.Close

       Else
       rsData.Close
       MsgBox "Error: No records returned", vbCritical
   End If

   Set rsData = Nothing


  End Sub
```

Comment: You just need to change your SQL, to say `">=" & Date()-7 & "` or something like that.  There will be a lot of stuff on the net about using dates in SQL, which will help.  You can then use a variety of techniques to find the last row and paste there.

Comment: If `Start_Date` is a datetime field, this query could not have worked in MS Access as dates do not allow quoted strings.

Comment: Try changing 2 things first   cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
  "Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb"  and the other thing is sSQL = "SELECT * FROM BP_Closed_Deals WHERE Start_Date between #10/21/2019# and #10/25/2019#"

Answer (score 0):

Consider finding last Monday and Friday's date relative to today using [`DatePart`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datepart-function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa):

```
 sSQL = "SELECT * FROM BP_Closed_Deals "_
         & "WHERE Start_Date BETWEEN Date() - (DatePart('d', Date()) - 2) - 7" _
         & "                     AND Date() - (DatePart('d', Date()) - 2) - 3"
```